# Thread is killed by hitting Powerbutton if the app is active

Tags: java, android, multithreading

in my app i've got a Thread and I call `startTimerThread()` in the `onCreate`

```
Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "What the hell is this for?");
        wl.acquire();
        while (true)
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //I do my stuff here
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {}
                }
            });
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});

private void startTimerThread()
{
    th.start();
}
```

The thread goes perfectly on, even if I press the "Back-Button" on my Android device and then press the Powerbutton.
But if I press the Powerbutton WHILE the app is running (so not hitting the "Back-Button" before) the thread is killed.
I've got no idea why this is happening ... Does anyone know a solution for that?

Comment: It's because you use runOnUiThread method.
Try to use AsyncTask.

Comment: Do I also use that in the the while-loop in the thread?

Comment: Could you please post the error logs from logcat?

Comment: I acctually dont get any errors. The only happening is, that the Thread stops (I checked that, by generating txt-files every 0.5 seconds, but that stopped immediately after hitting the Powerbutton)

Comment: Do you have "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" permission in the manifest?

Comment: If I use Async Task and press Powerbutton, my app crashes completely